# what is synonym of anchor in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm new in C#. Right now I'm using xaml to build application before it I had experience in JAvaFX. I used in javaFX anchorPane which can help to move items or make thier size bigger compare to window when window is small it has their own value but when you maximize of window items will change their value or position.How I can make this situation with C# more precisely with xaml Thanks

Comment: You can use `VerticalAlignment`/`HorizontalAlignment.Stretch` or `StackPanel` or `Grid` etc. Post some code and ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: Thank you Man. You are great it was enouph for me to work

Comment: XAML is just an xml-like text structure. You should specify your actual UI Technology like WPF, UWP or Xamarin. They all build on XAML, but the solution to your problem might be different.